# Insert CSV data into Bigquery table using Python

Tags: python, csv, google-bigquery

I'm trying to insert csv file into bigquery using python, but I think I have missed something since the result is replace,

```
from google.cloud import bigquery  
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=r"C:/Users/Pamungkas/Documents/Dump_Data/testing-353407-a3c774efeb5a.json"

client = bigquery.Client() 

table_id="testing-353407.testing_coba.Sales_Menu_COGS_Detail_Report"
file_path=r"C:\Users\Pamungkas\Downloads\Sales_Menu_COGS_Detail_Report_Jan.csv"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV, skip_leading_rows=1, autodetect=True,
        write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE 
)

with open(file_path, "rb") as source_file:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_id, job_config=job_config)
    
job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print(
    "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
        table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
    )
)
```

I guess the problem is in job_config, but I still didn't get it,
can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What is your expected result? Do you expect to append data?

Comment: yes, to append the data @RiccoD

Comment: Try changing the value of your `write_disposition` to `bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND`

Comment: Were you able to try it out?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @RiccoD, since you're appending the data from csv into BigQuery, you'll have to change the write disposition in job config to [WRITE_APPEND](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#:%7E:text=WRITE_APPEND%3A%20If%20the%20table%20already,returned%20in%20the%20job%20result.:%7E:text=the%20query%20result.-,WRITE_APPEND,-%3A%20If%20the%20table).

So change the job config part as:

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV, skip_leading_rows=1, autodetect=True,
        write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
```